# Como verificar se o usuário está online?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, websocket, chat

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em PHP e usando MySQL como banco de dados.
Só tenho uma dúvida sobre como fazer o bate papo: Como saber quais usuários estão online naquele exato momento?

Comment: 1-Não recomendo fazer um bate-papo usando apenas [tag:mysql] e [tag:php], por experiência ele vai ficar instável e de difícil manutenção. 2-se pretenderes mesmo usar [tag:php] recomendo que utiliza [tag:sockets]. 3-Minha principal recomendação é que utilize [tag:websockets] em [tag:javascript], além de ter uma manutenção mais fácil existem mais bibliotecas que fazem o que você precisa

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você pode usar um conjunto de técnicas para ter essa informação.

Do lado do cliente:

- Ouvir evento de fechamento da janela do browser, e quando usuário fechar, enviar um sinal para o servidor, indicando que o usuário possui uma janela a menos aberta, sendo que no servidor terá que contar quantas páginas o usuário possui abertas
- Ouvir evento de movimento do mouse, e se ficar por um certo tempo sem mexer o mouse, então o usuário é considerado offline

Para implementar o chat:

- a opção que vai te dar a maior abrangência em termos de browseres, é chamada de **long-polling**, mas também é a que vai dar mais trabalho. Veja mais sobre a técnica: http://rberaldo.com.br/server-push-long-polling-php-ios/
- um outra opção que vai ser mais fácil, é usar **websocket**, e criar uma conexão com servidor, que vai poder enviar mensagens quando algum evento do chat ocorrer... tipo enviar uma mensagem

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta já foi marcada como respondida, mas como referência para quem parar aqui futuramente: utilize [websockets](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), eles já estão por aí a algum tempo e são a solução mais adequada para comunicação em tempo real entre browsers e servers (um chat por exemplo). A ideia básica deles é manter uma conexão aberta constantemente entre clientes e o servidor para permitir comunicação em tempo real, você poderia emular isso usando ajax e [long-polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling), contudo a diferença de performance é relevante (pior neste caso) e long-polling é uma solução alternativa que geralmente só é preferível na ausência de mecanismos melhores.

Um dos únicos problemas com o uso de websockets seria a falta de suporte em browsers, um problema praticamente irrelevante já que agora [quase todos os principais](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) já tem suporte e a maioria (senão todas) as bibliotecas de websockets provém fallback automático para long-polling caso necessário.

No caso do problema de verificar quem está online seria simples, veja um exemplo usando [socket.io](http://socket.io/):

```
// código do servidor realtime
var onlineClients = {};
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    onlineClients[socket.id] = socket;

    // on disconnected, unregister
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete onlineClients[socket.id];
    });

    // usado em um exemplo mais abaixo
    socket.on('enviarMensagem', function(mensagem) {
        io.emit('novaMensagem', mensagem);
    });
});

// código do cliente (browser)
<script>
  var socket = io();

  // usado em um exemplo mais abaixo
  socket.on('novaMensagem', function(mensagem) {
      alert(mensagem);
  });
</script>
```

Quando um cliente conecta ou desconecta seu realtime server fica instantaneamente ciente e você pode tomar ações baseado nisto. Digamos por exemplo que você queira a partir do PHP enviar um "olá" para todo mundo que está on:

```
// código do servidor php, usando a elephant.io lib
$elephant = new Client($socketServerUrl);
$elephant->initialize();
$elephant->emit('enviarMensagem', 'ola');
```

Seu php server emitiria um evento 'enviarMensagem' para seu realtime nodejs server, que por sua vez emitiria o evento 'novaMensagem' para todos os clientes conectados, ao chegar neles seria disparado um `alert(mensagem);` com a mensagem enviada (veja os trecho de código com o comentário "usado em um exemplo mais abaixo").

Answer (score 1):

Dê preferencia a utilizar o websocket, mais caso voce possua um host compartilhado que nao de esse suporte segue algo que pode ajudar.

se caso vc criar um campo(EX: tempo) e em cada mensagem de texto ele atualizar esse campo com valor do time do php ( EX: $tempo=time() ) na area onde vc ira pegar o resultado use o seguinte select

> $consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE tempo > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 300";

no caso o UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 300 significa 5 minutos mais vc pode alterar para o tempo que quiser em segundos EX: UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 60 = 1 minuto

Comment: O seu código e lógica parecem ótimas, mas isso não funciona bem aqui desculpe parecer estar criticando, mas a questão é **websocket**, a resposta do miguel explica bem como o long-polling funciona e torna usar mysql para o servidor redundância e até desperdício, então entenda que em websocket a situação vai ser diferente de páginas normais. Por favor entenda apenas como uma critica construtiva, até mais ;)

Comment: Concordo plenamente , estou passando mais a informação caso o usuario use um host compartilhado que nao oferece esse recurso, fui até mal pois deveria ter especificado e irei fazer isso. OBS: quem dera todos membros tivessem o seu tipo de abordagem, parabens é de membros assim que o stack precisa

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas provavelmente a pessoa compartilha da minha opinião, não é de preferencia ou não sobre websocket, é exatamente só sobre websocket, mas como não foi o autor que colocou a tag websocket então vou considerar a sua resposta como alternativa para estes casos de servidores limitados (como os shareds) ;)

Comment: por isso especifiquei na atualizacao, quanto a regulamentos do site eu não muita trela pois regras existem para ser mudadas, estou até criando um post relacionado a isso pois vejo uma separação do pessoal aqui em muitas questões . Fica pra pergunta

Comment: Não existem "regras", existe modelo, quem define a regra é a comunidade e só porque você discorda do modelo ou regras não quer dizer que isso lhe permite fazer o contrário, as regras foram formadas por "pessoas" que com mais experiencias que nós dois e por bons motivos que só elas sabem o porque elas existem, cabe a nós seguirmos elas e debatermos talvez muda-las, mas não "desobedecer"... Claro que você não precisa seguir a regra ao pé da letra, mas se você for muito ao contrário você vai mais prejudicar do que ajudar...

Comment: ... Mas sobre a sua resposta não esta ruim só que ela seria melhor colocada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45125/usuarios-onlines-e-tempo-passado-no-site ... nessa pergunta a sua resposta fica perfeita ;)

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria usar Node.js (com o chat dentro de um iframe, conectando-se ao Node.js que seria um servidor separado do PHP), e Sockets.io como tecnologia básica. Existem inclusive diversos chats de exemplo escritos em socket.io que poderiam ser aproveitados como base (exemplo: http://socket.io/demos/chat/)

Comment: "O ideal" acho um pouco de exagero, Node.js é só mais uma das muitas possibilidades. Como exemplo, eu não trocaria o meu servidor Websocket que é super enxuto por Node.js, por exemplo. Como uma dessas alternativas, o Node.js poderia eventalmente servir. Fora isso, acho que faltou responder o que foi perguntado (afinal, a pergunta não é "como faço um chat", e sim como detectar se o usuário está online). Acho que dá pra melhorar a resposta.