# usuarios onlines e tempo passado no site

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Como eu posso obter a quantidade de usuarios online em meu site (instantaneamente), usando apenas PHP MYSQL e JQUERY? e respectivamente obter o tempo que o usuario passou em meu site

Comment: Já usou o Google Analytics? Ele faz isso.

Comment: Nao gostaria de usar serviços externos

Answer (score 6):

Uma das formas é manter atualizado no banco de dados o registro da última data que o usuário acessou o website e manter atualizado. Neste exemplo irei atualizar o cadastro a cada 10 segundos. Portanto se o último acesso dos usuários for recente, pelo menos nos últimos 60 segundos indica que esses usuários possivelmente estão online, afinal todos os dados são atualizados a cada 10 segundos.

**1. Banco de dados:**

```
CREATE TABLE visitas 
  ( 
     id          INT(11) UNSIGNED auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
     data_inicio DATETIME NOT NULL, 
     data_final  DATETIME NOT NULL 
  )
```

**2. Client-Side:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Repete a cada 10 segundos
setInterval(function () {
   // Post de contagem
    $.post("visitas.php", {contar: '',}, function(data) {
        // Exibe o número de online
        $('#Online').text(data); 
    });
}, 10000);

</script>

<span id='Online'>0</span>
```

A cada 10 segundos irá enviar um post para o PHP e esta requisição também irá obter a quantidade de usuários que estão online e irá mostra-lo no elemento de `id` igual a `Online`.

**3. Server-Side:**

```
if (isset($_POST['contar'])) {

    // Inicia sessão ou resume sessão existente:
    session_start();

    $data['atual'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data['online'] = date($data['atual'], strtotime("-1 minutes"));

    // Se o usuário já estiver online, existindo sessão:
    if (isset($_SESSION['visitante'])) {

        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Visitas SET data_final = '" . $data['atual'] . "' WHERE id = '" . $_SESSION['visitante'] . "'");

    }else{

        $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO Visitas VALUES (0, '" . $data['atual'] . "', '" . $data['atual'] . "')");

        $_SESSION['visitante'] = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($insert);

    }

    session_write_close();

    // Para retornar os últimos usuários online:    
    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(id) as Online FROM Visitas WHERE data_final >= '" . $data['online'] . "'");

    list($online) = mysqli_fetch_row($select);

    echo $online;

}
```

Sempre que receber o POST irá ver se existe ou não a sessão. Se houver, ele somente atualiza a última data. Se não, ele irá cria uma sessão. Depois, em ambos os casos, irá retornar o número de pessoas onlines (exibindo o número de pessoas que estão no banco de dados no minuto! Para saber o tempo de permanência basta subtrair o *data_final* - *data_inicial*.

Isso está bastante limitado e não está bem escrito, embora seja totalmente funcional existem mais critérios que podem ser adicionados além de um mero cookie de sessão.