# php vs nodejs performance em servidor de websockets

Tags: php, node.js, desempenho, memória, websocket

O que dou por certo atualmente é que nodejs é mais adequado para trabalhar com um pool constante de conexões por sockets (websockets neste caso) pois por ser single-threaded cada conexão nova gera um consumo de memória extra minímo (algumas centenas de KBs), já para php cada nova conexão geraria um novo processo que consumiria alguns megabytes extra.

Estou correto ou errado nessa ideia? independentemente da resposta, porque uma linguagem seria preferível a outra na implementação de um servidor de websockets?

Comment: Para quem tiver interesse, o que gerou esta pergunta foram estes comentários: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9566/como-verificar-se-o-usuário-está-online#comment236112_113233

Comment: Imagino que esteja errado, pois se for usar PHP, vai deixar o mesmo PHP rodando pra gerenciar todas as conexões, pois ele não seria rodado pelo servidor HTTP. Um exemplo, que não é de websockets, mas é comparável, é o SMTP da Guerrillamail. É um único serviço rodando, recebendo um numero gigantesco de conexões simultâneas sem o mínimo problema de performance, em PHP.

Comment: Pra complementar: esse servidor de SMTP em PHP é totalmente non-blocking IO, e usa uma thread só. Não seria problema nenhum usar o mesmo método para servir Websockets. Sockets normalmente trabalham bem com non-blocking em praticamente qualquer linguagem. Uma state-machine básica consegue gerenciar multiplas conexões com facilidade, e de sockets convencionais para Websockets, o que mais muda é a negociação inicial apenas.

Comment: @Bacco muito bom, foi o que eu disse na outra postagem ao bruno, provavelmente foi um engano que ele teve e o problema de memória que supostamente ele enfrentou com PHP foi com algum script "mal escrito": http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9566/como-verificar-se-o-usuário-está-online#comment236125_113233

Comment: Confusão total minha na comparação de nodejs vs php+apache, pois é o apache quem spawna novos processos para cada requisição e rodar nodejs atrás dele teria o mesmo resultado, assim não existe uma vantagem clara em nodejs em se tratando de memória por conexão como eu pensava. Contudo ainda é interessante vermos respostas com avaliações de ambas as linguagens neste caso, tem outros fatores para comparação como por exemplo o GC de php que é históricamente recheado de memory leaks (embora de uns anos para cá tenha melhorado muito) e nodejs é async nativamente.

Comment: Meu amigo, que edição foi essa aí? Isso não vai auxiliar/beneficiar outros usuários que tenha sua dúvida.

Comment: Fiz o rollback, porque ainda que "vago" ou que você tenha se confundido, ninguem respondeu e podemos reaproveitar a pergunta para falar somente sobre os websockets.

Comment: Eu uso php para websocket e estou satisfeito. E estou bem, obrigado. ;P

Comment: @BrunoRB editei a pergunta para focar apenas na questão de websocket que me parece interessante ainda.

Comment: A dúvida era uma confusão minha que achei que não seria relevante para outros então decidi cortar ela, mas se vocês acham que pode beneficiar outros tranquilo. Porém agora com a última edição ficou muito confuso, long-polling é diferente de websockets e "long-pooling constante de conexões" não parece fazer sentido. Vou reverter a versão original já que ninguém havia reclamado, mas nada contra edições para melhora-lá.

Comment: @BrunoRB ao invés de usar `<del>` e comentar que tinha um erro você deve DELETAR a pergunta, entenda por favor não somos um fórum, sendo um Q&A aqui deve haver uma pergunta e respostas, sendo assim a edição ali foi o que fez o pessoal vir aqui comentar, ela ficou bastante estranha. No caso editei, porque a duvida inicial surgiu sobre websockets e mesmo que tenha sido alguma confusão de entendimento já ouvi outras pessoas falarem que php é ruim pra determinada coisa, a pergunta pode ser bem recebida, vamos ver com o tempo.

Comment: Algumas referências para caso alguém queira formular uma resposta (eventualmente eu mesmo respondo caso não surja ninguém): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220501/websockets-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400541/are-websockets-suitable-for-use-with-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293734/html5-websockets-ideal-platform-for-php-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006761/websocket-server-with-php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Estou correto ou errado nessa ideia?

Você está parcialmente certo, ou parcialmente errado.

NodeJS funciona com um único processo, que executa um `loop de eventos`. Cada mensagem trocada, conexão que abre, conexão que fecha é um `evento`. Assim, em teoria, é mais fácil desenvolver aplicações websocket com NodeJs.

Com PHP você pode tentar fazer o mesmo criando um processo `long running` que se comunica com sua aplicação PHP. Já existem algumas bibliotecas para te ajudar nessa arquitetura:

- [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)
- [PHP-Push-WebSocket](https://github.com/srchea/PHP-Push-WebSocket/)
- [PHP Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)

Porém, se você quer algo bem mais parecido com o NodeJS, existe a extensão [PHPReact](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets).

### Porque uma linguagem seria preferível a outra na implementação de um servidor de websockets?

Em primeiro lugar vem o gosto. Use a linguagem que você gosta, mesmo que ela não tenha um desempenho tão bom quanto outras.

Em segundo lugar vem o mercado de trabalho. Se você cria um projeto que acaba virando um produto ou uma empresa, utiliza uma linguagem que seja mais fácil de encontrar pessoas para trabalhar com você.

Por último lugar vem custo. No futuro, se sua aplicação tem milhões de visitas e você quer economizar dinheiro, vale a pena trocar de linguagem, mesmo que essa linguagem não seja a sua favorita ou que não seja muito popular entre desenvolvedores. A Netflix migrou a aplicação que gera a interface do usuário de Java para NodeJS e assim reduziu os gastos com servidores em 70%. [NodeJs In Flames](http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/11/nodejs-in-flames.html)